# filtering numbers from array with the digit 5

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have simple array with numbers only. I simply need to filter from the array all the numbers that has 5 in it. examples of excluded numbers: 5, 56, 557,965 etc..
I got Strange behavior and only some of the numbers are deleted.

here's what I tried:

```
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];
const numbersStr = [];
// Turn "numbers" const to strings 
for (const number of numbers) {
  numbersStr.push(number.toString());
};

// filtering Fives
let counter = 0;
const noFives = numbersStr.filter(x => {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] == "5") {
      numbersStr.splice(counter, 1);
    }
  }
  counter++;
});
// end: filtering fives

// turn no fives to numbers
for (const strNumber of numbersStr) {
  let num = Number(strNumber);
  noFives.push(num);
}
console.log(noFives);  /* (5) [3, 56, 85, 105, 556]  */
```

The desired result should be [3] only.

Comment: In your code you use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I'd suggest you to take a look how to properly make use of the filter method

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues I see:

1. You're using `numbersStr.splice(counter, 1);` to remove a character from the string that you're looping through. That means that everything after the point where you've removed that character has been moved forward one slot. But since you're looping forward, and you don't do anything with your index variable when you remove the character, you'll skip your check of the next character. You want to either loop backward, or subtract one from `i` when doing the `splice`.
2. You're using `filter` incorrectly (as just a looping construct). `filter` is for creating a new array with only a subset of the entries from the original array. In your case, you're creating that array, but it will always be empty because your `filter` callback never returns a truthy value. (Later you fill in that array with entries from `numbersStr`.)

Typically you'd **either** remove the `5`s from the strings, **or** create an array with only the numbers that don't have `5`s in them, but not both.

To remove the entries with `5`s in them, you can use just `filter`, and you can use `includes("5")` (or `indexOf("5") !== -1`) to see whether the string contains the digit `5`:

```
const noFives = numbers.filter(number => !String(number).includes("5"));
```

Live Example:

```js
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];
const noFives = numbers.filter(number => !String(number).includes("5"));
console.log(noFives);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a one-liner using [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter elements of `numbers`, [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to convert each element to a string, and [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if this string contains 5:

```js
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];

const noFives = numbers.filter(x => !x.toString().includes("5"));

console.log(noFives);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I simply need to filter from the array all the numbers that has 5 in
> it.

I assume you want to filter the number which have 5 in it. In the filter callback just use `toString` to convert it into string and then use `includes`

```js
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];
const noFives = numbers.filter(x => {
  return x.toString().includes(5)
});

console.log(noFives); /* (5) [3, 56, 85, 105, 556]  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use `indexOf` function.

```js
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];
const noFives = numbers.filter(n => (n+'').indexOf('5') < 0);
console.log(noFives);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you

```js
const numbers = [3, 5, 56, 58, 85, 95, 105, 905, 556];
const numbersStr = [];
// Turn "numbers" const to strings 
for (const number of numbers) {
  numbersStr.push(number.toString());
};

// filtering Fives
let counter = 0;
let arrfive = [];
let noFive = [];
let flag = false;
const noFives = numbersStr.filter(x => {
  flag = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] == "5") {
      arrfive.push(x);
      flag = true;
    }
  }
  if(!flag){
    noFive.push(x);
  }
});

console.log(arrfive);
console.log(noFive);
```